# Best way to identify a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I apologize for the vague title. I'm trying to find a better way to do this:

```
public void DoSomething(Textbox tb)
{
    switch(tb.Name)
    {
        case "tbOne":
            // Do something
            break;
        case "tbTwo":
            // Do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't like hardcoding the textbox names because they can change and break my code. Any ideas on how to better do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to hard code it, just do this instead of what you have:

```
public void DoSomething(Textbox tb)
{
   if(tb == tbOne)
   {
   }
   else if (tb == tbTwo)
   {
   }
}
```

That way if they change you'll get a compile time exception =).

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Tag property of the Textboxes, it can hold anything (any object, string, int,...) you want.

In many cases you could find that what you are doing is not needed. If you add to your question what it is you are trying to accomplish you might get better suggestions.

Comment: can't emphasize the second paragraph enough... we human beings aren't known for getting it right the first time, so the more you tell us, the better the answer you get

Answer (score 0):

There should be an `UserData` entry somewhere in the dependency graph upwards, but can't find it on MSDN.

What about using the `Tag` property ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx)) to store a value you can use for identification?